# Alert Table in Mysql not deleting duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I'm deleting the duplicate rows from MySQL table but somehow the following query doesn't work and showing me

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE 'blocking_map' ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (block_key, id)
```

Error Msg:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE TABLE blocking_map ADD UNIQUE INDEX (block_key, id)' at line 1   0.000 sec

Comment: Also, you should use backticks, not single quotes, around table and column names. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: The `IGNORE` option has been removed from `ALTER TABLE` in MySQL 5.7. See the duplicate question for how to do this now.